# Python tell the worker thread to stop

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, while-loop, python-multithreading

Tkinter is running on the main thread, while there is a process running on the worker thread. In the Tkinter window, if the user clicks the 'STOP' button, the worker should stop.

I am using the while loop and for some reason, it does not work.

Please check the code below.

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import Tkinter as tk

class status:
    STOP = False

def stop():
    print 'User request to STOP the work'
    status.STOP = True

def worker():
    print 'worker starts'
    while not status.STOP:
        for i in xrange(10):
            print i
            time.sleep(1)
        print 'worker finishes'
    if status.STOP:
        print 'worker was interrupted'
        # wrapping stuff up.....
    else:
        print 'worker finished without interruption'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    tk.Button(root, text="STOP", command=stop).pack()
    Thread(target=worker).start()
    root.mainloop()
```

**Edit 1:**
I think I know why it does not work. If I understand correctly, the *condition* in the *while* loop is checked after going through the whole loop. However, I still don't know how can I deal with this situation.

**Edit 2:**
@smoggers answer (putting `if status.STOP in the`for i in xrange(10)` loop) would technically work but what if the worker process is much more complex?

See below code for new 'worker' function:

```
def worker():
    print 'worker starts'
    while not status.STOP:
        for i in xrange(10):
            print i
            time.sleep(1)
            print 'do some complex stuff'
            time.sleep(1)
            print 'do more complex stuff'
            time.sleep(1)
        print 'worker finishes'
    if status.STOP:
        print 'worker was interrupted'
        # wrapping stuff up.....
    else:
        print 'worker finished without interruption'
```

I would like it to be able to check the status **while** it is running each line of code. A stupid non-programming way to solve it is to put `if status.STOP: break` at each line of the code in the *for loop*. How to make the same effect but smartly?

Comment: well apologies for my 'stupid' answer

Comment: @smoggers I am sorry I did not mean like that. It's not a stupid answer, in fact as I state it's a correct answer. It would be stupid only in case there was more stuff going on in the for loop which I did not mention before so your answer was absolutely correct and it was my mistake to not stating that there is more process going on in the for loop.

Comment: cool, apology accepted